# Files in /var/log are only writing to file.1 (syslog is empty, but not syslog.1 )

Tags: ubuntu, logs, docker, syslog

The host is a docker container running Ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to figure out why the primary log files are not being written too, I have attached output of the files and permissions. I am hoping to figure out why this is occurring as my log files are not being written or rotated properly.

```
root@1485f0c1fad4:/var/log# ll
total 4124
drwxrwxr-x  9 root   syslog    4096 Oct  3 11:48 ./
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root      4096 Sep 26 06:25 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root         0 Oct  1 13:08 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     13742 May  9 10:26 alternatives.log.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Oct  1 13:08 apt/
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm          0 Oct  1 13:08 auth.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    2529538 Sep 30 23:10 auth.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     47816 Apr 12  2016 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw----  1 root   utmp         0 Oct  1 13:08 btmp
-rw-rw----  1 root   utmp         0 Apr 12  2016 btmp.1
-rw-r-----  1 root   adm         31 Apr 12  2016 dmesg
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root         0 Oct  1 13:08 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    279689 May  9 10:26 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      3264 Apr 12  2016 faillog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Apr 12  2016 fsck/
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm          0 Oct  1 13:08 kern.log
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm        109 Sep 25 15:27 kern.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp     29784 Apr 12  2016 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Sep 25 15:27 supervisor/
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm          0 Sep 27 06:25 syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    1262760 Sep 30 22:43 syslog.1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Apr 11  2014 upstart/
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp         0 Oct  1 13:08 wtmp
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp         0 Apr 12  2016 wtmp.1
```

Here is the potentially relevant information from the dockerfile, let me know if there is a problem with that syslog line.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential python-pip python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libssl-dev libffi-dev libkrb5-dev sshpass python-yaml cron git supervisor python-urllib3

# Syslog related
COPY misc/10-rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/01-rsyslog.conf

RUN echo "0-30/15 6-7 * * 6 root bash -c 'cd /root/xxx; python xxx.py >> /root/xxx/output/cron.log 2>&1'" >> /etc/crontab

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

rsyslog.conf

```
root@1485f0c1fad4:~/xxx# cat /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifemp

ty
            delaycompress
            compress
            postrotate
                    reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
            endscript
    }

    /var/log/mail.info
    /var/log/mail.warn
    /var/log/mail.err
    /var/log/mail.log
    /var/log/daemon.log
    /var/log/kern.log
    /var/log/auth.log
    /var/log/user.log
    /var/log/lpr.log
    /var/log/cron.log
    /var/log/debug
    /var/log/messages
    {
            rotate 4
            weekly
            missingok
            notifempty
            compress
            delaycompress
            sharedscripts
            postrotate
                    reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
            endscript
    }
```

Comment: Would you post your `/etc/logrotate.d/01-rsyslog.conf`? Looks like it's not the only one involved but it will help investigating.

Comment: Just updated with logrotate.d/rsyslog

Comment: @Pyhtonic Thanks. They look almost alike if I compare with mine. Is `notifempty` cut that way in your file? (I don't think it could be the cause though). Also, I have `invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null` instead of your `reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true` but if this comes from the default config of Ubuntu 14 (I'm running a 16) there's no reason for it to prevent the daemon from writing... Especially knowing that your `.1`files are not empty. (Thinking loud, sorry)

Comment: How are you managing the running services inside your container? i.e. what is the `CMD` in the Dockerfile. I'm guessing `reload rsyslog` command is not restarting rsyslog so it remains writing to the files that were moved to `x.1`.